# Jquery Mobile Close Loading Icon Issues

Tags: jquery, mobile

Hi Ladies and Gentlemen

I have recently ported my website to jquery mobile and after many hours of rewriting my desktop site to fit a smaller screen all went well. My issue is with the loading page spinner from many hours of messing around I can get the spinner to load up and display as I wish. I used the $(document).ready(function() and then added the $.mobile.loading( 'show'); inside which loads as expected however my issue is getting it to go away once the page has loaded, from the docs I assumed mobileinit would do the trick but it seems to fail. Here is a simple demo of the code I am using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Page Title</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function() {          
$.mobile.loading( 'show', {
    text: 'Loading',
    textVisible: true,
    theme: 'z',
    html: ""    
});
});

<!---- How do I stop the spinner after page has loaded ? Docs state mobileinit = Event indicating that jQuery Mobile has finished loading.--------------->
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
$.mobile.loading( 'hide');
});

        </script>
    </head> 

    <body>
        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="page">
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Testing loader</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead html comment use JS comment, at line `//How do...`, other than that, i'm not seeing anything wrong here

Comment: I think `mobileinit` event not firing

Comment: @Venkata Panga thanks any ideas why that could be ? appreciate your reply.

Comment: Added answer it should help!, jquery library need to be updated, and change the order of script blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of changes required!

- You're using old jQuery libraries, update them to latest stable version.
- Order of script for loading is important as below.

  1. Include `jquery.min.js`.
  2. Add `mobileinit event script fragment` this place is very important for mobileinit event-handler definition.
  3. Include 'jQuery.mobile.min.js`
  4. Add dom-ready script fragment.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.mobile.loading('hide');
            }, 1000);
        });
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.mobile.loading('show', {
                text: 'Loading',
                textVisible: true,
                theme: 'z',
                html: ""
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- /page -->
    <div data-role="page">
        <!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Testing loader</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks again I tried to revised code but the spinner fails to load now. I will have a mess around some more using your advice and see if I can fix the issue. Appreciate your efforts though.

Comment: Updated, moved `dom-ready loading('show')` to after JQM.js and added 1sec delay to hide function in `mobileinit handler`, i tested its working now.

Comment: Sorry first version I didn't tested completely, looked for when `mobileinit` event firing. This time we added delay timing to see the effect. On full page load for non-ajax calls, its very hard to see the loader when there is no content we have on the page.